# Adding Hibernate dependencies in Maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am trying to add Hibernate core and its dependencies within my Maven project.

I have this on my pom.xml

```
<!-- Hibernate Framework -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, it still not find the following libraries:

> org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

So is there any other depdencies that I still need to include in my pom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this page](http://grepcode.com/search?query=org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry&start=0&entity=type&n=) I'd say you don't have a dependency on a version of hibernate-core that actually provides this interface. You either need to use a different solution and not use these, or upgrade to at least version 4.3.0.Final.

Comment: yeah, it do the trick. Thanks. I'll accept the answer after 5 minutes.